# Comparing nested, non-linear models

Tags: regression, predictive-models, nonlinear-regression

I would like to compare the fit of two non-linear regression models:

1)
$$
Y = (\Pi^{10}_{i=1}\beta_i^{x_i})^{1/\Sigma \beta}
$$

2)
$$
Y = \begin{cases}
(\Pi^{10}_{i=1}\alpha_i \beta_i^{x_i})^{1/\Sigma \beta} & \text{for a predefined subset of datapoints} \\
(\Pi^{10}_{i=1}(1-\alpha_i)\beta_i^{x_i})^{1/\Sigma \beta} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Can I still use the F-statistic to compare the fit of these two models?

Comment: Presumably you will be referring the F-statistic to an F distribution. For that to be valid you need to assume (and verify) the usual assumptions on errors: zero mean, homoscedastic, uncorrelated, etc,--and that they are *additive*.  I bring up this point because it would be natural to take logarithms of both sides of these multiplicative models (which is tantamount to assuming multiplicative error in the original expressions), which would make them not quite so dreadfully nonlinear :-), so it is important to be as explicit about the error structure of your models as possible.